# Changing the currency culture of a field in access database

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have table `invoice` inside an access mdb that stores `DECIMAL` in Italian format. ie `,` is used as the decimal separator.

So thousand will be written as `1.000,00`. I would like to change it to UK format like this `1000.00`. For this I use this query.

```
UPDATE invoice SET invoice_amount = Replace(Replace(invoice_amount,'.',''),',','.')
```

Are there any better options? I am also afraid that an accidental run of this query a second time makes `1000.00` become `100000`. Any straight forward fool proof way to change culture here?

P.S: `invoice_amount` is of type `Text` here.

Comment: it feels counter-intuitive to work with culture in your db because it relates to data presentation, not data itself. Why not add culture specifics in your code?

Comment: @Wimbo: maintaining a code already written dude :)

Comment: Can you change the format of the field to Euro in the table or run code to do so?